# How do I close SQL Server output subwindow which appears when I run a T-SQL script from inside Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql

How do I close SQL Server output subwindow which appears when I run a T-SQL script from inside Visual Studio 2010? It neither has nay kind of control buttons like [x] or[-=] visible, nor any other obvious means of closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the keybinding to be whatever you like.

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

[image]

Find Data.SqlEditorToggleResultsPane, which is defaulted to Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R.  I changed mine to mimic SSMS (Ctrl+R), but you can change it to anything you like.

You can also add a custom shortcut button to a toolbar, if keybindings aren't your thing.

Answer (score 7):

On occasion the default keyboard shortcut Ctrl+R disappears. Resetting the default keyboard mapping scheme, using the [Reset] button in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard should cure this.

Answer (score 4):

The only way we found to do it was `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `R`.

Comment: I think I am going to need two hands for that one. :)

Comment: @Jersey Dude, it certainly is a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

'Window', 'Hide Results Pane' (Ctrl-R)

Comment: Does not work. There is no "Hide Results Pane" in "Window" menu. If I press Ctrl+R then "(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for sekond key of chord..." appears in the status bar.

Comment: Sorry, @Ivan - I was looking at my copy of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.